# Utilizando LIKE no MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando executar um SQL com LIKE no MySql sem sucesso, com algumas pesquisa percebi que o MySql so aceita o like depois de um where, mas na minha pesquisa não há a necessidade do where, pois estou querendo pesquisar todos os clientes cadastrados no banco que começam com a letra T.

Estou tentando executar a SQL desta forma:

> SELECT * FROM PARCERIA LIKE 'T%'

O MySql retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> Unrecognized keyword.

tem alguma outra forma de realizar esta pesquisa?
caso seja apenas por LIKE, tem alguma forma de utiliza-la sem o WHERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível. A cláusula `WHERE` é a condição que deve ser obedecida para retornar registros dentro do critério estabelicido.

Seu critério foi definido aqui:

> estou querendo pesquisar todos os clientes cadastrados no banco que começam com a letra T.

Comment: é que eu não tinha percebido que o LIKE e o WHERE são juntos e não separados, eu tinha feito um LIKE em android mas não usava o where junto, por isso achei estranho, depois fui entender, me desculpe pela burrice e muito obrigado pela ajuda! kkkkkkkkk